# Error message "error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported" while using react-scripts

Tags: reactjs, web-applications, frontend, npm-scripts

I entered `npm run start` command in terminal and got Error message **"error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported"** the complete error message is:

```
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:68:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:138:10)
    at module.exports (C:\FrontEndExcercises\06.react\React_The Complete Guide\complete-guide\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\FrontEndExcercises\06.react\React_The Complete Guide\complete-guide\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at handleParseError (C:\FrontEndExcercises\06.react\React_The Complete Guide\complete-guide\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:471:10)
    at C:\FrontEndExcercises\06.react\React_The Complete Guide\complete-guide\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:503:5
    at C:\FrontEndExcercises\06.react\React_The Complete Guide\complete-guide\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:358:12
    at C:\FrontEndExcercises\06.react\React_The Complete Guide\complete-guide\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\FrontEndExcercises\06.react\React_The Complete Guide\complete-guide\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\FrontEndExcercises\06.react\React_The Complete Guide\complete-guide\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
  npx update-browserslist-db@latest
  Why you should do it regularly: https://github.com/browserslist/update-db#readme
```

here is package.json file content:

```
{
  "name": "complete-guide",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.7",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.17.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "styled-components": "^6.0.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "set PORT=3008 && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

first I tried to update my browser list using `npx update-browserslist-db@latest`
then changed my default port to **3008** and after that use `npm audit fix --force` but it didn't works out.